# Intel chip ALWAYS above base clock speed

Tags: task-manager, intel-core-i7, cpu-speed, turbo-boost

My Intel chip is constantly running at a speed close to its max turbo frequency, even when the machine is relatively idle.  I recently had an issue with it running too slowly, and followed this advice, which fixed the slow speed:

1. Shutdown the laptop
2. Unplug it
3. Keep the power button pressed for 45 seconds

I want to verify that I didn't mess anything up and that this behavior is healthy for the processor.  I'm nervous that constantly running at this speed is bad for the processor.  Please see details and prior research below.  Thanks for your help!

Chip:

- Intel i7-8750H has a base speed of 2.2 GHz and a maximum turbo frequency of 4.1 GHz ([Intel specs](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/134906/intel-core-i7-8750h-processor-9m-cache-up-to-4-10-ghz.html)  )
- Machine: Lenovo Legion Y7000P-1060 laptop
- Observation: When the laptop is plugged in, processor speed (as seen in both Task Manager and Intel's Processor Identification Utility) is ALWAYS between 3.8 GHz and 4.05 GHz, with utilization ranging but at times below 5%.  Fan is generally low, except when doing more intensive work (e.g. gaming, video editing).  When on battery, the processor speed changes much more dynamically as I'd expect.
- Intel Processor Diagnostic Utility: Everything passed
- Power Plan Settings: Minimum processor state set to 5%

What can I do?

Comment: Intel Boost is not actually based on the CPU usage.  If your processor is running at the boosted frequency it was designed to run at I don't understand the problem.

Comment: Speed will change very fast all the time. The Task Manager is not a good tool for that. See what happens with [CPU-Z](https://www.cpuid.com/softwares/cpu-z.html), CPU tab, Multiplier field. Did you examine what your installed tasks are doing?

Comment: If you tap on your battery in the taskbar in Windows is it set to "best performance" while charging? If so drop it down to recommended. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/customize/desktop/customize-power-slider That slider will change depending on whether you are charging or on battery.

Comment: Oh my gosh yes that explains it.  I figured that sort of stuff would also be found in the control panel menus but I guess not...   I'll digest both of these comments into an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Digesting an answer out of the comments.  Thanks for your help, commenters!

My processor was staying in the 'turbo boost' range persistently because I had my Battery Settings set to 'Best Performance' when my laptop was plugged in.  Changing the Battery Setting to 'Better Performance' allows the clock speed to fluctuate as I expect.  This setting is found by clicking on your battery on the taskbar, and it's a different set of options than 'Power Options.

More broadly, the high clock speed isn't a problem.  The processor is designed to use turbo boost, and as mentioned in the comments, turbo boost isn't necessarily based on CPU usage.  So this behavior was intended considering my Battery Settings.